# How to create a regex pattern for splitting at specific chars?

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a `Splitter` (guava) and split a string based on a regex pattern. The split should take place either on `[` or on `..` character.
And what if I want to include eg 10 characters for a split? Would I have to separate each of them by `|` in the regex?

But the following does not work:
`Pattern.compile("[|..")`

Test: `test[me..once more` should result in

```
test
me
once more
```

Comment: `..` is _not_ a character but a string. Besides that, since the dot and the bracket have special semantics, try to escape them for the literal: `"\\[|\\.\\."`

Comment: `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("[|.."));`

Comment: @MarounMaroun that would quote the pipe as well, which is not what he wants.

Comment: @Thomas oh.. didn't note that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/dU4mU2/2) to split:

```
(?:\[|\.\.)
```

In Java, you will have to escape the `\`s.

```
String str = "test[me..once more";
String pattern = "(?:\\[|\\.\\.)";
String[] parts = str.split(pattern);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as it also uses an unnamed group.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern does not work because `[` and `.` are control characters in regexes.

try escaping them like `Pattern.compile("\\[|\\.\\.")` (remember, `\` also needs to be escaped)